# A preposition for "define"

Tags: prepositions, word-request

I wrote this sentence

> The content of a node is extracted if it matches the conditions that are defined **(over/on/by/using)** the attributes of the node and the context.

Which preposition is used for define in this case? Conditions are defined by means of the attributes of the nodes and the context. for example suppose a condition stating the node tag must be "H1".

Answer (score 2):

You can use either *by* or *using*, but they have different meaning.

With the preposition *by*, *attributes* is the **agent** that performs the action of *defining*:

> The content of a node is extracted if it matches the conditions that are defined **by** the attributes of the node and the context.

If you use the gerund *using* instead, then the *attributes* become the means, the instrument with which the agent performs the action of *defining*, but those *attributes* are not the agent themselves. They are what the agent uses to perform the action:

> The content of a node is extracted if it matches the conditions that are defined **using** the attributes of the node and the context.

So, you must ask yourself whether you see those *attributes* as the agent or not and then select your preposition or gerund accordingly.

Comment: I gave an example in the question, I think attributes are used in the definition of a condition. For example suppose condition is defined as " height above 170 cm", here the attribute is "height", how they relate?

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'by' or 'using':

> The content of a node is extracted if it matches the conditions that are defined **by** the attributes of the node and the context.
>
> The content of a node is extracted if it matches the conditions that are defined **using** the attributes of the node and the context.

The difference is subtle, and probably not so important.